# Injecting a private key into web3.js execution context

Tags: web3js, web3-providers

I'm trying to achieve what seems like a simple goal but having trouble finding a simple solution to it. Here's my problem:

**Given a private key, I would like the simplest way to "inject" this key into a web app context so that all subsequent usage of the `web3` object uses this as `web3.eth.defaultAccount`.**

Before someone brings up security issues, I would like to emphasize that we can ignore security implications for now. It's a special case and I have solutions to deal with the security issue as long as this is possible.

The only solution I've found so far has been to create a custom provider and instantiate the `Web3` instance with this custom provider which overrides certain methods like `sendTransaction`, etc.--this is how MetaMask seems to work using https://github.com/MetaMask/provider-engine.

But setting up all these custom providers just for what I'm trying to achieve--**take a private key string and turn it into `web3.eth.defaultAccount`**--feels like an overkill.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Did you research web3 v1.0? It has [web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#privatekeytoaccount) (I didn't try that api yet). For web3 v0.20 I've used [truffle-hdwallet-provider](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-hdwallet-provider), it uses MetaMask's provider-engine but it easier to setup (Although you have to provide the mnemonic instead of the raw private key).

Comment: @Ismael Yes indeed! I actually found the solution after I posted and just managed to get it to work just now. I can confirm this works. The trick is to inject it into web3.eth.wallet

Comment: It should be good if you write what are you doing so it can help others in similar situation.

Answer (score 11):

Using web3js 1.0.0:

```
const privateKey = 'e0f34403.................................29c8c861937';
const account = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount('0x' + privateKey);
web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add(account);
web3.eth.defaultAccount = account.address;
```